# Where can I find an interrupt list for i486-linux-gnu instruction set?

Tags: linux, assembly, gnu, compiler-construction, gnu-assembler

I am developing a compiler for my senior project in school, and I am using AS (GNU Assembler) to assemble. All of my tests have been fairly successful, but no interrupt lists I have seen have seemed to work or match up with my test code.

The relevant information for this version of AS:

*GNU assembler 2.17 Debian GNU/Linux
Copyright 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License.  This program has absolutely no warranty.
This assembler was configured for a target of `i486-linux-gnu'.*

Comment: Why do you need to handle interrupts? Don't you mean system call list, rather than interrupt list?

Answer (score 3):

In linux, you use one interrupt: 80h. The syscall which that interrupt corresponds to can be found in [this table](http://bluemaster.iu.hio.no/edu/dark/lin-asm/syscalls.html).

Answer (score 2):

Linux does not use interrupts for system calls the same way DOS does. It uses an architecture-dependent method to make system calls, which on x86 can be int 0x80, but modern (Pentium+) CPUs should use the SYSENTER instruction instead. Other software interrupts aren't used.

Normally you don't worry about this, because even in assembly language, you'll probably still want to use the C library, which wraps these.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the way interrupts are hooked up is hardware specific. It may be educational to look how the Linux kernel deals with interrupts on the hardware you are targeting.